# How to prevent IE11 and Microsoft Edge from throttling events aggressively?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

### Background

I have a pannable app window which works by listening for `mousemove` events and then using `transform: translate3d(...)` to move the screen accordingly. It's a large app and there is considerable UI work associated to facilitate this functionality. Here comes the MCVE, in which the real workload is mocked by a dummy `for` loop:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var contents = document.getElementById("contents");
var input = document.getElementById("iterations");

var posX = 50;
var posY = 50;
var previousX = null;
var previousY = null;

var mousedownHandler = function (e) {
    window.onmousemove = globalMousemoveHandler;
    window.onmouseup = globalMouseupHandler;
    previousX = e.clientX;
    previousY = e.clientY;
}

var globalMousemoveHandler = function (e) {
    var now = Date.now();
    for (var i = 0, n = parseInt(input.value); i < n; i++);
    var elapsed = Date.now() - now;

    posX += e.clientX - previousX;
    posY += e.clientY - previousY;
    previousX = e.clientX;
    previousY = e.clientY;
    contents.style.transform = "translate3d(" + posX + "px, " + posY + "px, 0)";
    contents.innerText = elapsed + "ms";
}

var globalMouseupHandler = function (e) {
    window.onmousemove = null;
    window.onmouseup = null;
    previousX = null;
    previousY = null;
}

container.onmousedown = mousedownHandler;
contents.style.transform = "translate3d(" + posX + "px, " + posY + "px, 0)";
```

```css
#container {
  height: 180px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#container:active {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<label>Iterations: <input id="iterations" type="number" value="20000000" step="5000000" /></label>

<div id="container">
    <div id="contents">
        Pannable container contents...
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example with larger drag-area](https://jsfiddle.net/mjcjvapo/3/)

***Please hold and drag the example.***

*This rudimentary snippet runs a dummy `for` loop every time `mousemove` fires, and the duration it takes for the loop to complete is displayed in the draggable container. This is needed to demonstrate the problem below. You may need to adjust the number of iterations, so that the loop takes somewhere above 10ms to run, but not much longer.*

### Problem

This snippet runs as fast as possible in Google Chrome, no problems there. Untested in Firefox.

However, in Microsoft Edge *(and presumably, IE11 as well)* if `globalMousemoveHandler` runs for longer than about 10ms, the browser starts throttling the event mercillesly, making it fire much less frequently, and obliterating the panning progress down to a crawl.

Also quite strange is that the `for` loop actually runs *faster* in Microsoft Edge than in Chrome (almost 50% faster), but the event still fires *much* less frequently.

This is observable in the above snippet when viewed from the mentioned browsers. Now I understand the theoretical desire behind this functionality, but it renders my application *unusable* on these browsers -- I also don't really understand what's the point for the throttling to kick in below 16ms *(I'm well under the 60 FPS frame budget)*, but that's besides the question now *(although I'd be glad to hear some details about this)*.

**How can I prevent this from happening?**

Comment: If you think its the mouseevent is causing the problem, then just take it outside the event, you could use either setTimeout, setImmediate, postmessage etc.

Comment: @Keith The problem with that is that it introduces an at least +16ms additive latency, in which case I would need to _detect_ if this throttling kicked in. That said, `requestAnimationFrame` is a much better _workaround_ for [doing that](https://jsfiddle.net/mjcjvapo/4/).

Comment: Yes, it's why I said etc.  You could maybe even place inside a webworker.

Comment: @Adosi Correct, this is detailed in the question.

Comment: I suppose I just don't understand your problem. Rather than attempting to workaround native IE/Edge rendering behaviour why couldn't you just make your JS more efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that uses [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var contents = document.getElementById("contents");
var input = document.getElementById("iterations");

var posX = 50;
var posY = 50;
var previousX = null;
var previousY = null;

var mousedownHandler = function (e) {
    window.onmousemove = globalMousemoveHandler;
    window.onmouseup = globalMouseupHandler;
    previousX = e.clientX;
    previousY = e.clientY;
}

var globalMousemoveHandler = function (e) {
    posX += e.clientX - previousX;
    posY += e.clientY - previousY;
    previousX = e.clientX;
    previousY = e.clientY;
  
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {        
      var now = Date.now();
      for (var i = 0, n = parseInt(input.value); i < n; i++);
      var elapsed = Date.now() - now;

      contents.style.transform = "translate3d(" + posX + "px, " + posY + "px, 0)";
      contents.innerText = elapsed + "ms";
    });
}

var globalMouseupHandler = function (e) {
    window.onmousemove = null;
    window.onmouseup = null;
    previousX = null;
    previousY = null;
}

container.onmousedown = mousedownHandler;
contents.style.transform = "translate3d(" + posX + "px, " + posY + "px, 0)";
```

```css
#container {
  height: 180px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: grab;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#container:active {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<label>Iterations: <input id="iterations" type="number" value="20000000" step="5000000" /></label>

<div id="container">
    <div id="contents">
        Pannable container contents...
    </div>
</div>
```

This stops the heavy lifting from blocking the handler function, effectively preventing the issue from happening, at the cost of a 16ms increased latency.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that too,.. I wonder if's it's more to do with cascading setTimeouts, one solution is to make sure only 1 setTimeout is running at a time.  I'll just do a quick mod.

Comment: Ok done.. :)  `(why didn't I think about this...)`  Sometimes, problems just need somebody to look at them from another angle.  Or sometimes, the next day it comes to you. :)

Comment: Just a though, that 16ms latency could be scrubbed too, IE has built in support for setImmediate, and for others there is a polyfil -> https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` has this issue on Chrome, since v39.

Comment: `setImmediate` would be awesome, because it is only supported in browsers where it is actually needed now. So it's a _delay with `setImmediate` if possible, call synchronously otherwise_ situation that's convenient, but it is introducing a _massive_ latency here. But as a hack, `requestAnimationFrame` can be used if `setImmediate` is present.

Comment: In the meantime, I've come across an interesting observation: the throttling was actually caused because `mousemove` is fired _faster than the framerate itself_! In which case, this solution can be padded with a manual throttling of events to synchronize their occurrence to the framerate by mixing [cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) into the process.